# How do I top:5.6px this 'Email a Friend' link?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

ANSWERED: All I had to do was add `.spyr_sb_mail .spyr_sb_inner {top:5.6px}` to my style.css.

the css file rule `div.spyr_sb_inner { position: relative; top: 6px; }` currenlty controls the facebook like button, twitter tweet button, the pinit pinterest button and the email a friend link. For that rule `div.spyr_sb_inner` all 4 buttons are connected for some reason. I would love to simply just edit the css but I don't know what rule is soley controlling the email a friend link.

So that is why I am looking to change the email a friend link's line of html :

`<div class="spyr_sb_inner">`

to this

`<div class="spyr_sb_inner" style="top:5.6px">`

but I don't know what php file to change. My goal is to move the 'Email a Friend' text `top:5.6px` as seen here:

```
<div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_mail">
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-mail">
      <span>Email a Friend</span>
   </a>
  <div class="spyr_sb_inner" style="top:5.6px">
      <a href="mailto:?subject=iOS 8&amp;body=I found value in this and I think you will too.%0A%0AiOS 8: http://boasish.com/ios-8/style=" top:5px""="">Email a Friend</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looked like originally:

[image]

This is what it would look like with `top:5.6px`
[image]

The php file I think I have to edit is themes/tru/includes/lib/spyr_slidingshare/init.php line 109 to 114 but nothing I tried has worked, I don't know where to put the css elment `style="top:5.6px"`

```
'mail' => array(
                'name' => __('Email a Friend','themins'),
                'widget' => '<a href="mailto:?subject=[title_encode]&body=' . __('I found value in this and I think you will too.','themins') . '%0A%0A[title_encode]: [permalink]">' . __('Email a Friend','themins') . '</a>'
                )
            );
        }
```

I am using a Genesis Framwork with a tru spyr.me Chiliad Theme for my Wordpress website http://boasish.com. I don't know how to accomplishlish what I want to do in css so that's why I am trying to edit the html. I am open to any kind of solution.

Comment: Why don't you do that via an external stylesheet?

Comment: Within your CSS file the the following rule: `div.spyr_sb_inner { position: relative; top: 6px; }` for instance.

Comment: This might be helpful: [CSS Basics Genesis Framework](http://www.web-savvy-marketing.com/2013/09/css-basics-genesis-framework/)

Comment: @HashemQolami that css file rule `div.spyr_sb_inner { position: relative; top: 6px; }` currenlty controls the facebook like button, twitter tweet button, the pinit pinterest button and the email a friend link. For that rule `div.spyr_sb_inner` all 4 buttons are connected for some reason, so that is why I am trying to add a `top:5.6px` to the email a friend link's html. I would love to simply just edit it in the css but I don't know what  the rule is called that is controlling the email a friend link.

Comment: It was just an example. It depends on your HTML structure which we are not aware of it. There should be a way to target that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

well, your code is quite incomplete because I don't know which is the container for those social icons, but assuming it is `.spyr_sliding_share_button` , open your style.css file and add these lines at the bottom:

```
.spyr_sliding_share_button{display:block}
.spyr_sliding_share_button a{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle}
```

this should do the trick. Otherwise, post more relevant code. What you're trying to do is a no-no

Comment: That didn't work and I am not trying to edit the `spyr_sliding_share_button` I'm trying to edit the `spyr_sb_inner`

Comment: as I said, your code is incomplete. And I'm targeting your `<a>` element that says "Email a Friend", as your image shows. Now I see in that code that you have it twice (?), so try changing the class to `.spyr_sb_inner`, but really, without proper code I just can't do much